# Bash: Combine creating a file and storing the Path in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, file, path

Is there a way to create a file and store the path into a variable in Bash?

```sh
ENV_FILE=./.projects.env
echo > $ENV_FILE
```

How can I achieve this in one command?

Edit:

From the suggestions in the comments below, it could be done like so:

```sh
ENV_FILE=$(> ./.projects.env && echo './.projects.env')
```

Comment: What you're doing is truncating the file; `ENV_FILE` already contains the path to the file, did you mean `echo "$ENV_FILE"`?

Comment: Hi, I mean, `./.projects.env` is an empty, (most of the time) nonexisting file, and I want to create it or empty the contents and use the file path later in the script. I wonder if there is a command, which simplifies those two steps into one

Comment: Just `> "$ENV_FILE"` would result in an empty file at that path, but your command should also work. Did you encounter problems with it?

Comment: Oh, I see, "one command".

Comment: But then, I still need the first line of the script, which set the Filepath to the Parameter ENV_FILE ^^, but  > $ENV_FILE is still shorter than `echo > $ENV_FILE` :) ty

Comment: I have edited my question with a one-line script, but they kind of look the same XD  

Comment: I find the two lines much more clear and don't see any advantage of using a one-liner, to be honest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227917/discussion-between-ki-hyoun-kim-and-benjamin-w).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ENV_FILE` is not already set, you can use this:

```
echo > "${ENV_FILE:=./.projects.env}"
```

Note: if `ENV_FILE` *is* already set to a non-null value, this will leave it unchanged and use its existing value. From the Parameter Expansion section of the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> `${parameter:=word}`
>
> **Assign Default Values**. If `parameter` is unset or null, the expansion of `word` is assigned to `parameter`. The value of
> `parameter` is then substituted. Positional parameters and special
> parameters may not be assigned to in this way.

BTW, using `echo` this way will not fully erase the file, it'll replace its contents with a newline (essentially, a single blank line). For a truly empty file, just don't use any command:

```
> "${ENV_FILE:=./.projects.env}"
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon, this answer is on point.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```sh
FILE_NAME=<a file name>
ENV_FILE=$(touch "$FILE_NAME" && realpath "$FILE_NAME")
```

replace `<a file name>` with the the name you want to give.

Comment: You need the file name to be stored somewhere in advance though, right?
**Edit**: or someone has to provide it

Comment: I mean, `realpath` could work out, it would reduce my code to a one-liner

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have used echo instead of realpath

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to repeat the filename (and eliminate potential typos), you can do this instead...

```
ENV_FILE=$(> ./.projects.env && echo !$)
```